# Transparent PNG Going Black

Tags: php, png, transparent, alpha

I have looked through so many other threads with people having trouble with a png image going black where it should be transparent and none of the solutions have worked for me.

Maybe I am going wrong else where in the code? Maybe imagealhpablending isnt supported by my web server?

Thanks for anyone that can help.

```
        $photo = imagecreatefrompng( "{$thumb_folder}{$new_file_name}" );
        $width = imagesx($photo);
        $height = imagesy($photo);

        $new_width = 32;
        $new_height = floor($height / ($width / $new_width)); 

        $temp_photo = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

        imagealphablending($temp_photo, false);

        imagesavealpha($temp_photo, true);

        $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($temp_photo, 255, 255, 255, 127);

        imagefilledrectangle($temp_photo, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $transparent);

        imagecopyresampled($temp_photo, $photo, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

        imagepng($temp_photo, "{$thumb_folder}{$new_file_name}" );
```

Answer (score 0):

The first colour allocated to an image is always the background colour anyway, so there is no need to draw that filled rectangle. Remove it from the code, and see what you get.